# Throwing exception in c#, guard

Tags: c#, exception

I had a discussion today about refactoring this (#1)

```
public void MyFunc(object myArgument)
{
    if(myArgument == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("myArgument");
....
```

With this (#2)

```
//inside a shared assembly in a class called Guard
public static void AgainstArgumentNull(object obj, string message)
{
    if (obj == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(message);
}

public void MyFunc(object myArgument)
{
    Guard.AgainstArgumentNull(myArgument, "myArgument");
....
```

My intuition was that #1 was better for the following reasons:

1. #1 is simpler than #2 in the sense that it requires no knowledge of Util library, just basic c# knowledge
2. #1 will not remove the resharper ability to rename the string passed to ArgumentNullException constructor.
3. #2 will increase the dependencies for the code (must have access to the dll containing the dll)
4. The stacktrace will not be the same for #2 as it would be for #1

My questions here are: 
Is my intuition correct?
Could the fact that we are throwing the exception from another assembly not become trouble in some scenarios?

Comment: You can configure R# to generate your custom `Guard` statements. Works like a charm and feels even better than before

Comment: How about reducing code nesting and therefore increase readability in #2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For this particular case, you shouldn't be using `Guard` anyway. You should be using Code Contracts.**

```
Contract.Requires(myArgument != null);
```

Comment: Will this really do the same runtime as the above for a release build?

Comment: @Casper Leon Nielsen: You can set it up to do so, yes.

Comment: Somebody should say that code contracts is an awful idea, badly supported implementation, and makes cry everyone who use it more then two weeks in a real project.

Answer (score 3):

You can also benefit from #2 in standardizing your exception handling to some degree across multiple projects; the abstraction also enables the library to be enhanced at a latter time and redistributed e.g. error logging for instance.